# Why does a query with a sub-select cost less than query with a constant in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, toad

I've got an SQL-table with some million entries and I tried to query how much entries are older than 60 days (Oracle 11.2.0.1.0).

For this experiment I used 3 different versions of the select-statement:
(The cost-value is given by TOAD for Oracle V. 9.7.2.5)

1. `select count(*) from fman_file

   where dateadded >= (select sysdate - 60 from dual)`
   Cost: 65
2. `select count(*) from fman_file

   where dateadded >= sysdate - 60`
   Cost: 1909
3. `select count(*) from fman_file

   where dateadded >= sysdate - numtodsinterval(60,'day')`
   Cost: 1884
4. `select count(*) from fman_file where dateadded >= '10.10.2009'`
   Cost: 1823
   (The 10.10.2009 is just an example-date!!!)

I don't have the accurate time-values for all queries in mind, but the first one really was the fastest.

So I tried some more select-queries with other subselects (like (Select 1000 from dual)) and they were (sometimes WAY) faster than the others with constant-values. It even seems that this "WHATEVER" (Bug/Feature) is happening in MySQL too.

So can anyone tell me why the first query is (way) faster that the others?

Greetz

P.S.: This ain't about the sydate! The question is WHY IS THE VARIATION WITH THE (Select) FASTER THAN THE OTHERS? (with a little focus on Select-Variation(1.) vs. Constant-Variation (4.))

Comment: Can't tell you why, but if you're trying to determine the counts of records OLDER than 60 days, isn't your relational operator reversed?

Comment: I can reproduce this effect also on 10.2.0.2.0, but the difference is much smaller: 4723 with subselect, 4736 with simple comparison.

Comment: A lower "cost" doesn't necessarily mean "faster". Although it might have some value in a very simple query like yours, normally you cannot compare cost values from one query to another. Their purpose is to compare different *plans* for the same query.

Comment: @ Jeffrey Kemp:
u r right, but i've executed the queries serval times and it REALY was faster! (like i wrote above:
Qoute: "I don't have the accurate time-values for all queries in mind, but the first one really was the fastest.")
@DCookie:
Typing mistake. :)

Comment: Question still not answered... could someone push it pls?

Answer (score 3):

Found some hints in my copy of "Cost-Based Oracle Fundamentals" by Jonathan Lewis in chapter 6 "surprising sysdate". This seems to apply to 9i, probably also later versions.

> The optimizer treats sysdate (and trunc(sysdate) and a few other functions of sysdate) as known constants at parse time, but sysdate + N becomes an unknown, and gets the same treatment as a bind variable - which means a fixed 5% selectivity. (Note in particular that sysdate + 0 will give a different cardinality from sysdate.)

Apparently the optimizer also recognizes the `select sysdate from dual` as a known constant.

Answer (score 1):

[Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388):

> The advantage to dual is the optimizer understands dual is a special one row, one 
>   column table -- when you use it in queries, it uses this knowledge when developing the 
>   plan.

Answer (score 0):

Did you re-try numbers 2-4 with () around the calculation after the >= -- it seems to me the first statement is the only one where it calculates that value once -- for all the others it recalculates on every row.
eg:

```
select count(*) from fman_file where dateadded >= (SELECT sysdate - 60) 

select count(*) from fman_file where dateadded >= (SELECT (sysdate - numtodsinterval(60,'day'))

select count(*) from fman_file where dateadded >= (SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'10.10.2009'))
```

NB -- don't know the syntax to convert to a datetime in Oracle -- but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Explain Plan`. This will show you what the queries are doing and the differences between them.

A couple of links to setup and use explain plan:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/explainplan.html

Answer (score 0):

instead of using **(select sysdate - 60 from dual)** i'd rather recommend you using a bind variable, which value is calculated before the query become executed